# Where is the Quranic verse of 5 suckling?

Tags: quran, source-identification, rada

**Sahih Muslim Book 008, Hadith Number 3421**
Chapter: One suckling or two do not make marriage unlawful.

> 'Aisha (Allah be pleased with, her) reported that it had been revealed in the Holy Qur'an that ten clear sucklings make the marriage unlawful, then it was abrogated (and substituted) by five sucklings and Allah's Apostle (May peace be upon him) died and it was before that time (found) in the Holy Qur'an (and recited by the Muslims).

**Sahih Muslim Book 008, Hadith Number 3422.**
Chapter: One suckling or two do not make marriage unlawful.

> 'Amra reported that she beard 'Aisha (Allah he pleased with her) discussing fosterage which (makes marriage) unlawful; and she ('Aisha) said: There was revealed in the Holy Qur'an ten clear sucklings, and then five clear (sucklings).

Can anyone point to the "substituted five clear (sucklings)" verse in the Quran?

Comment: No this isn't possible as this Verse doesn't exist and most ancient scholars say this hadith is an ahaad and therefore can't by any means be built on to prove or deny anything in the Qur'an! Only Scholars from the Shafi'i madhab used to take it as is see also: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8406/abrogation-of-verses-10-feedings-of-baby-to-make-foster-relationship-to-5/27726#27726

Answer (score 1):

Annaskh (النسخ) / abrogation is three kinds:

1. What has been abrogated both in recitation (Meaning there is no Ayah in the Quran) and ruling
2. What has been abrogated recitational we (Meaning cannot be found in an Ayah) but not in ruling
3. What has been abrogated in ruling, but can still be recited

These are the three kinds of abrogation, and as is clear in the Hadith, the ten sucklings goes in the first category, but the five sucklings go in the second category, meaning there is no recited Ayah in the Quran which says this as it has been abrogated in this sense, but it's ruling stays.

Comment: according to your argument above verse comes under which point 1, 2 or 3. please bring forth your proof for this and explain it. i cant accept some theory by scholars without proof

Comment: Does that mean that it _was_ in one of the suras of the Quran and isn't anymore?

Answer (score 0):

And what this means is that the abrogation by five sucklings was revealed very late to the extent that when the Prophet (peace be upon him) died, some people were still reciting the verse of five sucklings and making it part of recited Qur'an for they were not informed about its abrogation but when they were after that, they went back on that and formed a consensus on that this verse must not be recited. And abrogation is of three types: One of them is that its ruling and recitation be abrogated just like the ten sucklings verse. And the second is that its recitation has been abrogated without its ruling just like the five sucklings verse... (Muhammad Shams al-Haqq al-Adhim Abadi, Awn al-Mabud Sharh Sunan Abu Dawud, Kitab: Al Nikah, Bab: Hal Yuhharram Ma Doona Khamsa Ridaa'aat, Commentary on hadith no. 1765, Source)