# Is it generally understood by this hadith that verses were removed from the Quran after they were revealed?

Tags: quran, hadith-interpretation

> إِنَّ اللَّهَ بَعَثَ مُحَمَّدًا صلى الله عليه وسلم بِالْحَقِّ وَأَنْزَلَ عَلَيْهِ الْكِتَابَ فَكَانَ مِمَّا أَنْزَلَ اللَّهُ **آيَةُ الرَّجْمِ**، فَقَرَأْنَاهَا وَعَقَلْنَاهَا وَوَعَيْنَاهَا،
>
> Allah sent Muhammad with the Truth and revealed the Holy Book to him, and **among what Allah revealed, was the Verse of the Rajam** (the stoning of married person (male & female) who commits illegal sexual intercourse, and we did recite this Verse and understood and memorized it

See full hadith here:  [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/86/57)

**Is it generally understood by this hadith that verses were removed from the Quran after they were revealed?**

*I understand that many [scholars have argued that verses from the Quran have been "overridden" by other verses](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39857/15201). But in theses cases, the verses are not removed from the Quran, so that is not the same as mentioned in this hadith. Therefore my question.*

Comment: Relevant: http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=5195&idto=5196&bk_no=53&ID=782

Comment: Also relevant: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/how-to-reconcile-allahs-infallibility-with-naskh

Comment: There is even a "hadith" on the authority of Ubay ibn Ka'ab saying that surat al-Ahzab was as long as al-Baqara. Also read ([13:39](https://legacy.quran.com/13/39))

Answer (score 1):

The Qur'an actually affirms that Allah may delete/remove (if He wants to) or keep (if He wants to) in the Qur'an as He wishes:

> Allah eliminates what He wills or confirms, and with Him is the Mother of the Book. ([13:39](https://legacy.quran.com/13/39))

This verse actually is in full accordance to any hadith saying that there are parts of the Qur'an that have been removed (See also in [qtafsir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2288&Itemid=68)).

The hadith only shows one out of many examples, some you may even find quoted here on the site like:

- [Where is the Quranic verse of 5 suckling?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12534/where-is-the-quranic-verse-of-5-suckling)? which actually is a discussed matter (See for example [Abrogation of verses 10 feedings of baby to make foster relationship to 5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8406/abrogation-of-verses-10-feedings-of-baby-to-make-foster-relationship-to-5))
- [Was Dua-e-Qunut part of the Quran earlier?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39912/was-dua-e-qunut-part-of-the-quran-earlier/47950)
- [Do these hadith discredit all other hadiths?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35476/do-these-hadith-discredit-all-other-hadiths)

Comment: Reading that verse in its context (which speaks about older revelations from ahlu kitab) it might mean that He eliminates from their old customs what He wills. I think this is mentioned in some tafsir collections too. So if that is the case, that is why I referred my question to the hadith. I. e is it from the hadith which we can conclude that verses were removed from the Quran after they were reveled?

Comment: @Kilise if you could provide a tafsir saying so that would be nice actually the speech seems about the Qur'an as an Arabic legislation the quotation of ahl-al-Ktiab is only to show that they have got their revelation too.

Comment: I think I read it in Zamakhshari tafsir, please check, I might be wrong.

Comment: @Kilise az-Zamakhsari -in his [al-Kashaf](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=204&surano=13&ayano=39)- actually doesn't really agree with my statement, but he also don't explicitly agree with yours so I'd say it is not the source of the statement. After checking al-Qurtoby, ibn Kathir etc.: One could say that the majority consider this verse to be about qadar and rizq only qtadah agreed with my interpretation. Sa'id ibn Jubayr and Qatadah said it is about the legislations according al-Baghawi ....... You could call me Qatadah from now on ;)

Comment: Then I might have read it in Razis tafsir where he explains different interpretations of the verse.  I am aware of the majority view

Comment: @Kilise I can't confirm that also ar-Razi even counted ten interpretations -one honestly could say even more- the closest I found to what we both quoted is that of Sa'id ibn Jubary and Qatadah. Else he basically discusses whether this ruling is general or particular and mainly close to the majority view.

Answer (score -3):

yes, why not? it is fully compatible with quran itself: 2:106: https://quran.com/2/106 , http://www.islamawakened.com/quran/2/106/default.htm :

> We do not abrogate a verse or cause it to be forgotten except that We
>   bring forth [one] better than it or similar to it. Do you not know
>   that Allah is over all things competent?

let's look at original words: http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=2&verse=106
-> http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=nsx -> http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D9%86%D8%B3%D9%8E%D8%AE%D9%92
-> http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=nsy -> http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D9%86%D9%8E%D8%B3%D9%90%D9%89%D9%8E

so, one word is about nullifying or replacing, another word is about making to forget.

it is said that anything such thing has some replacement in quran. it is probably 24:2, 5:33 and 4:15-16 in this case:

https://quran.com/24/2 :

> The [unmarried] woman or [unmarried] man found guilty of sexual intercourse - lash each one of them with a hundred lashes, and do not be taken by pity for them in the religion of Allah, if you should believe in Allah and the Last Day. And let a group of the believers witness their punishment.

https://quran.com/5/33 :

> Indeed, the penalty for those who wage war against Allah and His Messenger and strive upon earth [to cause] corruption is none but that they be killed or crucified or that their hands and feet be cut off from opposite sides or that they be exiled from the land. That is for them a disgrace in this world; and for them in the Hereafter is a great punishment,

https://quran.com/4/14-17 :

> (15:) Those who commit unlawful sexual intercourse of your women - bring against them four [witnesses] from among you. And if they testify, confine the guilty women to houses until death takes them or Allah ordains for them [another] way. (16:) And the two who commit it among you, dishonor them both. But if they repent and correct themselves, leave them alone. Indeed, Allah is ever Accepting of repentance and Merciful.

Comment: I don't feel this is answering my question. I am already familiar to the scholars opinions of verses being abrogated by others, as i mentioned in my question: *"I understand that many scholars have argued that verses from the Quran have been "overridden" by other verses. But in theses cases, the verses are not removed from the Quran, so that is not the same as mentioned in this hadith. Therefore my question."* Could you edit your question and answer accordingly? I'd like some good scholar opinion references too. Because my question is about a hadith, quoting verses from the Quran won't help.