# Which sunni scholars deny naskh tilawa (removed verses from the quran)?

Tags: islamic-scholar, naskh

I understand that most scholars believe in [abrogated verses in the Quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39857/15201), while they differ on the conditions needed to claim a verse to be abrogated. Some fully deny the theory of abrogation in the Quran. [Some scholars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNm5tPosL5I) seems also deny naskh tilawa (i.e removed verses from the Quran).

**Which sunni scholars deny naskh tilawa?**
*These scholars also (or automatically) deny the ahadith which speaks about certain verses been removed from the quran, such as the one mentioned in this [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39822/15201), and the hadith of Aicha ([1](https://sunnah.com/muslim/17/30),[2](https://sunnah.com/urn/1320210)).*

*When I mention scholars in my quesiton, I include (all kinds of) scholars: hadith, al-usuliyoun (of usul al fiqh), fiqh, tafsir.*

Comment: This could easily turn into an opinion-based question, unless criteria for _khilaf mo'atbar_ (scholarly differences) are pre-defined, as almost all of the so-called scholars that deny abrogation these days do not rise at all to the level of _khilaf mo'atbar_, hence their denial has no scholarly value, e.g., the linked video provided in the question. I suggest that you define the criteria for _khilaf mo'atbar_ in your question.

Comment: @III-AK-III Are you saying Ali Gooma has no scholarly value?

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by not defining criteria for _khilaf mo'atbar_. Scholarly value is not person-specific, but a person-topic relationship. For example, Ibn Hazm was specialized in jurisprudence, not hadith. This does not mean that Ibn Hazm has no scholarly value, but it means he was not a hadith scholar. Dr. Ali Gomaa studied jurisprudence, not science of Qur'an or hadith. If the question was which Qur'an scholars denied naskh, it would be a different story.

Comment: @III-AK-III I've edited my question. I don't want to get into an discussion, just an answer of which scholars denied naskh tilawa. One doesn't have to agree with them or think they've reached a high level enough to deny such things. That would be a different question.