# If my mother breastfed my aunt once, would that turn her into my sister from rida'a? and their children become my mahrem or not?

Tags: halal-haram, mahram, rada

asalamu'alaikom wa rahmatu allah wa baarakatu,
I have a question that I couldn't find the answer. Let me explain. My mother breastfed my aunt when she was a baby. That makes her become my Rida'a sister ? . And if so, are her children my mahram or are they still my cousins?
thank you for taking the time to try to explain this topic baaraka allahu fikom.

Answer (score 1):

There is disagreement on the number of times that breastfeeding must occur for it to be counted. The majority considers once to be sufficient. See [Marrying a man whose mother breast feeded only once to the girl](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50090/)

If a woman X breastfeeds a woman Y then Y becomes like her daughter, and and all the descendants of Y become like the descendants of X. However it will not effect the ancestors or siblings of Y nor the other children of the ancestors or siblings of Y.

Hence if your mother breastfed your aunt then your aunt is like your sister. And her children are like your nieces.

> قال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم في بنت حمزة لا تحل لي، يحرم من الرضاع ما يحرم من النسب، هي بنت أخي من الرضاعة
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said about Hamza's daughter, "I am not legally permitted to marry her, as foster relations are treated like blood relations (in marital affairs). She is the daughter of my foster brother."
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2645)</sup>